# Can not get Auth login from Spring Security 5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

create a simple spring security configuration on spring boot 2 m6

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Bean
    public ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsRepository() {

        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("test")
                .password("test")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user);
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf()
                   .disable()
                   .authorizeExchange()
                   .anyExchange().authenticated()
                   .and()
                   .httpBasic().and()
                   .build();
    }
```

but when i try to get authentification object in handler request after authenfication i always get null

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().block().getAuthentication()
```

and when i try to get login as

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> checkStatus(ServerRequest request) {
        System.out.println(request.principal().block());
```

i also get null

where is the problem ?

Comment: If your mention class is belongs to `WebSecurity` then `SecurityConfig` class should extends perhaps `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` *(Don't know that webflux change it or not. But somehow you need to override the default one)*.

Comment: with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter it will not work because i use netty and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter require servlet filter

Comment: even I am facing the same issue. I am not using Spring Boot through I am using Spring Security Webflux 5.0.0.M5

Comment: now the is the webflux rc1. please try that version